# looping over set inside map in cpp

Tags: c++

I am getting error in for loop ,compiler saying that 's' must have a pointer type (in `s->second.begin()`).I just want to iterate over set below.

```
vector<vector<int>> verticalTraversal(TreeNode* root) {

    map<int, map<int, set<int>>> mep;

    solve(root, 0, 0, mep);
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    for (auto p : mep) {
        vector<int> temp;
        map<int,set<int>> s = p.second;
        for (auto ity = s->second.begin(); ity != s->second.end(); ity++) {    
 //getting error here in s->second.begin()


        }

        //reverse(temp.begin(), temp.end());
        result.push_back(temp);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195966/discussion-on-question-by-user11736087-looping-over-set-inside-map-in-cpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to write a small program, and then get an idea/experiment with the smaller program to understand the basic concepts.

Here is an example:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::map<int, std::set<int>>> mep;
    mep.insert({0, {{0, {0,1,2,3}}}});   // populate the map
    mep.insert({1, {{1, {1,2,3,4,5}}}}); // populate the map
    // traverse each set in the mep map
    for (auto p : mep) 
    {
        std::map<int, std::set<int>> s = p.second;
        for (auto ity = s.begin(); ity != s.end(); ity++) 
        {    
           std::set<int>& theSet = ity->second;
           for (auto& setV : theSet )
               std::cout << setV << " ";
           std::cout << "\n";
        }
     }
  }
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Also note that you really should be using references to the data within the map instead of copying them by value.  Things like this:

`for (auto p : mep)` 
and
`std::map<int, std::set<int>> s = p.second;`

incurs a copy.  Rather, you should do this:

`for (auto& p : mep)`
...
`std::map<int, std::set<int>>& s = p.second;`

Answer (score 3):

So here's some code that iterates through each set (and prints out all the integers).

```
vector<vector<int>> verticalTraversal() {

    map<int, map<int, set<int>>> mep;

    solve(root, 0, 0, mep);
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    for (map<int, map<int, set<int>>>::iterator i = mep.begin(); i != mep.end(); ++i) {
        for (map<int, set<int>>::iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); ++j) {
            for (set<int>::iterator k = j->second.begin(); k != j->second.end(); ++k) {
                cout << *k << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

First thing you should notice is that there are three loops not two, since you have a set inside a map inside a map you have three levels to iterate though (not two as in your code).

Second thing is I removed all `auto` and all range based loops and been completely explicit about the types involved. Hopefully that makes the code easier to understand.

Once you've understood it you can put the auto back in if you like, or even replace the loops with range based loops.

Comment: taking into account that you arent sober nice answer :P

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 God, yes, wouldn't have managed it without the compiler checking my work.

Comment: seriously, its a nice example for why the "almost" should not be left out in "almost always auto". its nice when the types are obvious, but in the worst case `auto` can hurt readability